# InvalidOperation at /orders/ [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I am going to add delivery cost to total price in project but it does not work. Both fields are `Decimal` but it throws this error `InvalidOperation at /orders/ [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]`. Here is **Delivery price model**

**Traceback**

```
  File "/home//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1115, in to_representation
    value = decimal.Decimal(str(value).strip())
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

**models.py**

```
class DeliveryPrice(models.Model):
    shipping_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_charge = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

and it is the `FK` to `Order` model.

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price_of_delivery = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['phone', 'address', 'price_of_delivery']

def create(self, validated_data):
    price_of_delivery = validated_data.pop('price_of_delivery')
    price_instance, created = DeliveryPrice.objects.get_or_create(shipping_charge=price_of_delivery)
    order_instance = Order.objects.create(**validated_data, price_of_delivery=price_instance)
    return order_instance
```

**views.py**

```
total_aggregated_dict = cart.aggregate(
            total_price=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'), output_field=DecimalField()))
        print(total_aggregated_dict)
        order_total = total_aggregated_dict['total_price']
        delivery_price = self.request.data['price_of_delivery']
        print(delivery_price)
        final_total = Decimal(order_total) + Decimal(delivery_price)
        print(final_total)
        order = serializer.save(user=user, total_price=final_total)
```

this is all what I have tried so far. To be clear, firstly, user adds product to cart then they can order when they fill order fields (address, phone number, etc) they also select shipping cost and this selected shipping cost should be added to total price. But in my case it is not working I am getting error above shown. How can i tackle this issue? Any help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the error traceback

Comment: Could you also add `Order` model? As you are using `'__all__'` fields

Comment: @NalinDobhal please have a look

Comment: @ArturSiepietowski plaese have a look

Comment: I understand the OP has now resolved the issue, but I had the error being caused by storing a Boolean value in a BIT field in mysql. When I returned the value it treated it as a Decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

my mistake was with serializer because I am setting `price_of_delivery` to `DecimalField` and in the views I am also converting to `Decimal`. I just have changed `serializers.DecimalField` to `serializers.CharField` and everything is working well.